# How to get Android Documents folder storage permissions in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

In my flutter app, I am trying to save a file downloaded from an API. It is sufficient to save the file to the Downloads directory, regardless of the file type.

My Android `compileSDK = 32`. I understand that `permissions_handler 10.0.0` does not support the API 33 permissions. I downgraded to `9.2.0` and it compiles.

`path_provider 2.0.11` does not support Android directories so I hard coded the path.

I am using

```
dio: ^4.0.6
path_provider: ^2.0.11
permission_handler: ^10.0.1
```

I get the following permissions error in the android studio console when I try to save the file. Request log included for completeness.

```
I/flutter (11956): app documents path: /data/user/0/com.example/app_flutter/fatsquid.jpg
I/flutter (11956): permission status: PermissionStatus.granted
I/flutter (11956): app external storage path: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example/files/fatsquid.jpg
I/flutter (11956): hard path string: /storage/emulated/0/Download/fatsquid.jpg
I/flutter (11956): actual path used: /storage/emulated/0/Download/fatsquid.jpg
I/flutter (11956): file save path
I/flutter (11956): /storage/emulated/0/Download/fatsquid.jpg
I/flutter (11956): *** Request ***
I/flutter (11956): uri: https://api.example.com/transcript/download/transcript/file/1
I/flutter (11956): method: GET
I/flutter (11956): responseType: ResponseType.stream
I/flutter (11956): followRedirects: true
I/flutter (11956): connectTimeout: 0
I/flutter (11956): sendTimeout: 0
I/flutter (11956): receiveTimeout: 0
I/flutter (11956): receiveDataWhenStatusError: true
I/flutter (11956): extra: {}
I/flutter (11956): headers:
I/flutter (11956):  authorization: Bearer secret
I/flutter (11956): 
I/flutter (11956): *** Response ***
I/flutter (11956): uri: https://api.example.com/transcript/download/transcript/file/1
I/flutter (11956): statusCode: 200
I/flutter (11956): headers:
I/flutter (11956):  content-type: application/octet-stream
I/flutter (11956):  date: Fri, 23 Sep 2022 06:55:43 GMT
I/flutter (11956):  vary: Origin
I/flutter (11956):  content-length: 497741
I/flutter (11956): 
E/flutter (11956): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot create file, path = '/storage/emulated/0/Download/fatsquid.jpg' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)
```

Here is my code:

```
class FileDownloadView extends StatefulWidget {
  const FileDownloadView({super.key});

  @override
  State<FileDownloadView> createState() => _FileDownloadViewState();
}

class _FileDownloadViewState extends State<FileDownloadView> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(
      (_) => showSnackBar(context),
    );
    super.initState();
  }

  String received = "0";

  String progress = "0";

  bool downloading = false;

  bool isDownloaded = false;

  String filename = 'file-name-not-set';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    User user = Provider.of<User>(context, listen: false);

    Company company = Provider.of<Company>(context, listen: false);

    filename = user.downloadFileName;

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          company.companyName,
          maxLines: 1,
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          style: TextStyle(
              color: appTextColor,
              fontSize: user.fontsize,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
        ),
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: () => {
            Navigator.of(context)
                .pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(RoutePaths.matter, (route) => false)
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [appBackgroundColorStart, appBackgroundColorEnd],
              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
              end: Alignment.bottomCenter),
        ),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                SizedBox(height: 24),
                SizedBox(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: Text(
                    'Download $filename: $received',
                    maxLines: 4,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: appTextColor,
                        fontSize: user.fontsize,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 24),
                ElevatedButton.icon(
                  onPressed: () {
                    downloadMobileFile(user);
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.download),
                  label: const Text('Download'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> downloadMobileFile(User user) async {
    log('downloading with mobile function ');
    setState(
      () {
        downloading = true;
        filename = user.downloadFileName;
      },
    );

    checkWritePermission();

    String savePath = await getFileSavePath(user.downloadFileName);

    print("file save path");
    print(savePath);

    final storage = FlutterSecureStorage();

    String? token = await storage.read(key: 'jwt');

    Dio dio = Dio();

    dio.interceptors.add(LogInterceptor(responseBody: false));

    dio.download(
      user.fileUrl,
      savePath,
      options: Options(
        headers: {HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Bearer $token'},
      ),
      onReceiveProgress: (rcv, total) {
        setState(
          () {
            progress = ((rcv / total) * 100).toStringAsFixed(0);
            received =
                'received: ${rcv.toStringAsFixed(0)} out of total: ${total.toStringAsFixed(0)} $progress%';
          },
        );
        if (progress == '100') {
          setState(
            () {
              isDownloaded = true;
            },
          );
        } else if (double.parse(progress) < 100) {}
      },
      deleteOnError: true,
    ).then(
      (_) {
        print('download progress: $progress');
        print('is the file downloaded: $isDownloaded');

        setState(
          () {
            if (progress == '100') {
              isDownloaded = true;
            }
            downloading = false;
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }

  static Future<void> checkWritePermission() async {
    if (!kIsWeb) {
      if (Platform.isAndroid || Platform.isIOS) {
        var permissionStatus = await Permission.storage.status;

        print('permission status: $permissionStatus');

        switch (permissionStatus) {
          case PermissionStatus.denied:
          case PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied:
            await Permission.storage.request();
            break;
          default:
        }
      }
    }
  }

  Future<String> getFileSavePath(String uniqueFileName) async {
    String path = '';
    Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String appDocPath = appDocDir.path + '/' + uniqueFileName;
    print('app documents path: $appDocPath');

    final Directory? externalDir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
    String externalPath = externalDir!.path + '/' + uniqueFileName;
    print('app external storage path: $externalPath');

    Platform.isAndroid
        ? path = '/storage/emulated/0/Download/$uniqueFileName'
        : path = '$appDocDir.path/$uniqueFileName';

    print('hard path string: $path');

    print('actual path used: $path');

    return path;
  }
}
```

Edit: I updated this code to incorporate suggestions below and edited my manifest to include this code below:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="28"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />

   <application
        android:label="example"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Dont delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I am able to save the file successfully to `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example/files/fatsquid.jpg` which is supplied by `getExternalStorageDirectory()` but is not a satisfactory solution as most users would have difficulty locating the file. It needs to be in the Documents folder which I understand to be the path I have hard coded.

Comment: Permission.storage is for Scoped Storage only (internal app folders). I would recommend starting with the Android MediaStore documentation which should allow you to save files to the shared Downloads folder: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media and then find a Flutter package that enables the features you need in Flutter, or create your own platform channels for them.
The alternative way to get direct access to those paths is with the special Permission.manageExternalStorage, which requires you to fill out a Permission Declaration Form when submitting the app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Android compileSDK 33 The solution is not to use `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` but use the flutter [saf](https://pub.dev/packages/saf) package. My `AndroidManifest.xml` has no changes from default.

`build.gradle`:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"

        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 33 // flutter.targetSdkVersion
```

`pubspec.yaml`:

```
  dio: ^4.0.6
  path_provider: ^2.0.11
  permission_handler: ^9.2.0
  saf: ^1.0.3+3
```

My complete code for a download page is here:

```
const directory = "/storage/emulated/0/Download/";

class FileDownloadView extends StatefulWidget {
  const FileDownloadView({super.key});

  @override
  State<FileDownloadView> createState() => _FileDownloadViewState();
}

class _FileDownloadViewState extends State<FileDownloadView> {
  late Saf saf;
  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(
      (_) => showSnackBar(context),
    );
    Permission.storage.request();
    saf = Saf(directory);
    super.initState();
  }

  String received = "0";

  String progress = "0";

  bool downloading = false;

  bool isDownloaded = false;

  String filename = 'file-name-not-set';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    User user = Provider.of<User>(context, listen: false);

    Company company = Provider.of<Company>(context, listen: false);

    filename = user.downloadFileName;

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          company.companyName,
          maxLines: 1,
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          style: TextStyle(
              color: appTextColor,
              fontSize: user.fontsize,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
        ),
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: () => {
            Navigator.of(context)
                .pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(RoutePaths.matter, (route) => false)
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [appBackgroundColorStart, appBackgroundColorEnd],
              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
              end: Alignment.bottomCenter),
        ),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                SizedBox(height: 24),
                SizedBox(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: Text(
                    'Download $filename: $received',
                    maxLines: 4,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: appTextColor,
                        fontSize: user.fontsize,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 24),
                ElevatedButton.icon(
                  onPressed: () {
                    downloadMobileFile(user);
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.download),
                  label: const Text('Download'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> downloadMobileFile(User user) async {
    log('downloading with mobile function ');
    setState(
      () {
        downloading = true;
        filename = user.downloadFileName;
      },
    );

    checkWritePermission();

    String savePath = await getFileSavePath(user.downloadFileName);

    //print("file save path");
    //print(savePath);

    final storage = FlutterSecureStorage();

    String? token = await storage.read(key: 'jwt');

    Dio dio = Dio();

    dio.interceptors.add(LogInterceptor(responseBody: false));

    dio.download(
      user.fileUrl,
      savePath,
      options: Options(
        headers: {HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Bearer $token'},
      ),
      onReceiveProgress: (rcv, total) {
        setState(
          () {
            progress = ((rcv / total) * 100).toStringAsFixed(0);
            received =
                'received: ${rcv.toStringAsFixed(0)} out of total: ${total.toStringAsFixed(0)} $progress%';
          },
        );
        if (progress == '100') {
          setState(
            () {
              isDownloaded = true;
            },
          );
        } else if (double.parse(progress) < 100) {}
      },
      deleteOnError: true,
    ).then(
      (_) {
        setState(
          () {
            if (progress == '100') {
              isDownloaded = true;
            }
            downloading = false;
          },
        );

        print('download progress: $progress');
        print('is the file downloaded: $isDownloaded');
      },
    );
  }

  Future<void> checkWritePermission() async {
    if (!kIsWeb) {
      if (Platform.isAndroid || Platform.isIOS) {
        var permissionStatus = await Permission.storage.status;

        switch (permissionStatus) {
          case PermissionStatus.denied:
          case PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied:
            await Permission.storage.request();
            break;
          default:
        }

        await saf.getDirectoryPermission(isDynamic: true);

        print('permission status: $permissionStatus');
      }
    }
  }

  Future<String> getFileSavePath(String uniqueFileName) async {
    String path = '';
    Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String appDocPath = appDocDir.path + '/' + uniqueFileName;
    print('app documents path: $appDocPath');

    final Directory? externalDir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
    String externalStoragePath = externalDir!.path + '/' + uniqueFileName;
    print('app external storage path: $externalStoragePath');

    Platform.isAndroid
        ? path = '/storage/emulated/0/Download/$uniqueFileName'
        : path = '$appDocDir.path/$uniqueFileName';

    print('hard path string: $path');

    print('actual path used: $path');

    return path;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps,
use `provide_paths.xml` to access to storage

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
    <root-path
        name="external_files"
        path="/storage/" />
</paths>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
```

```
<application

 <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:initOrder="100"
            android:permission="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provide_paths" />
        </provider>
</application>
```

Comment: Does provide_paths.xml go in `android/app/src/main`?

Comment: Add it in res XML folder.

Comment: These changes made no difference. I still get a permissions error 13 when I try to save to `/storage/emulated/0/Download/fatsquid.jpg`.

Comment: use latest version permission_handler: ^10.0.1,

Comment: I upgraded to `permission_handler ^10.0.1` but it made no difference.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> add this,gave forcefull permission in app settings

Comment: https://cdn.ourcodeworld.com/public-media/gallery/gallery-6101a954a3904.png like this

Answer (score 0):

This method Works for me :

```
static Future<void> checkPermission() async {

    if (!kIsWeb) {
      if (Platform.isAndroid || Platform.isIOS) {
        var permissionStatus = await Permission.storage.status;

        switch (permissionStatus) {
          case PermissionStatus.denied:
          case PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied:
            await Permission.storage.request();
            break;
          default:
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

And in manifest you need to add the permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="28"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
```

And inside application :

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

Edit

```
<application
        android:label="my app"
        tools:replace="android:allowBackup,android:icon,android:label,android:roundIcon,android:theme"
        android:isGame="false"
        android:testOnly="false"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:logo="@mipmap/launcher_icon"
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/launcher_icon"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
```

For tools error , you can put the propeery tools in xml root node.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example"
    xmlns:dist="http://schemas.android.com/apk/distribution">
```

Comment: What is your `compileSDK` version?

Comment: compileSdkVersion and target is 32

Comment: why do you include `android:maxSdkVersion="28"`?

Comment: This permission is deprecated for Android 10 and above... Só, with this line Android 10 and above don't read this permission

Comment: Which file and position do I include `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
`?

Comment: In manifest inside application . I edited my anwser to put an example

Comment: I edited my question to show the result.

Comment: You can put xml tools in manifest. Check the edit

Comment: I got the error after I applied your changes, please check my code.

Comment: U see my last edit?

Comment: No change, I get the same permissions error as above

Comment: After update the code your app requisitei again the permission?

Comment: Yes, it did request the permission again which I approved.

Comment: Sorry for the delay @markhorrocks
What is the value of permissionStatus in this line:
 var permissionStatus = await Permission.storage.status;

Comment: Permission status: `PermissionStatus.granted`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider), you can just use Application Documents Directory to store the file. That way, you won't have to deal with storage permission.

```dart
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
String appDocPath = appDocDir.path;
```

With the help of [dio package](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) which also you are already using, downloading and storing file is super easy.

```dart
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

final Dio dio = Dio();
String ext = 'pdf';

// Download and store file
dio.download(yourFileUrl, '$appDocPath/$fileName.$ext').then((value) {
   // any you want to do after download is finished
});
```

To read the downloaded files from the Application Documents Directory again. You can do this

```dart
import 'dart:io';

Directory(appDocPath).exists().then((exists) {
List<FileSystemEntity> files = [];
  if (exists) {
    files = Directory(appDocPath).listSync();
  }

  return files;
});
```

Comment: `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()` gives me a final path `/data/user/0/com.example/app_flutter/fatsquid.jpg` which downloads successfully but I am unable to find this path in my file explorer.

Comment: You won't find it in file explorer because it is in the app. File explorer can only read from external storage. 

If you need to display the downloaded images in your app you need to read it from the app directory again. I can provide the code for you.

But if you want your app users to see them from File Manager app, you must deal with storage permission and my code won't be valid anymore.

What do you want?

Comment: I need to resolve the storage permissions. Users should be able to find the downloaded file in the expected location, the Downloads folder. Or at least the Documents folder. I don't want my app to open the file.

Comment: Yes, if you are not showing them in your app. They are indeed the expected locations.  I added the code to read the downloaded files anyway.